# Hapi route throws 404 on production whereas works on localhost

Tags: node.js, routes, http-status-code-404, production-environment, hapi

I have a node application that runs perfectly on localhost. All the routes are run and respective responses are sent back. When the same is deployed on production, only the healthcheck route throws 200 with response whereas other routes throw 404 error.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');


const server = new Hapi.Server({
    port: 3000
});

server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/healthcheck",
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        logger.log(["info", "stdout"], "Checking health");
        const response = h.response({"message", "Server is UP and running"});
        response.code(200);
        return response;
    }
});
const init = async () => {
    try {
        await server.start();
        logger.log(['info'], 'Server successfully started');
    }
    catch (err) {
        logger.log(["error"], err);
    }
    server.route([{
        method: "POST",
        path: "/route/service1",
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            logger.log(["info", "stdout"], "Request received for route/service1");
            
            payload = await customFunction1(request.payload);
            response = h.response(payload);
            response.code(200);
            return response;
        }
    },{
        method: "POST",
        path: "/route/service2",
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            logger.log(["info", "stdout"], "Request received for route/service2");
            
            payload = await customFunction2(request.payload);
            response = h.response(payload);
            response.code(200);
            return response;
        }
    }
    }]);
};

init();
```

Below is the response thrown on production

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Not Found"
}
```

Is there anything that am missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

Hapi may return 404 Not found when your CORS is not configured correctly. Surprisingly, it's not going to display any meaningful error to indicate that. See how to configure [CORS for Hapi](https://hapi.dev/api/?v=21.3.3#-routeoptionscors).

Code example:

```js
server.route({
   method: 'post',
   path: '/upload',
   options: {
      cors: {
        headers: ['Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type'],
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000', ...]
      }
   },
   handler: r.handler
})
```